# Why does IE not show JQuery UI dialog form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have code to display a JQuery Modal dialog:

```
        if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog();
        } else {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
        }

        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          },
          close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        });
```

and here is the HTML:

```
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Select Employee">
        <form id="dialogForm">
            <fieldset>
                <select id="employeeList"> <option value="0"><%=LocalizedContext.SelectAnEmployeeText%></option> <%=model.EmployeeOptions%> </select> 
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And it shows fine in FF, but when it pops up in IE, the dialog is there (with cancel button), but the dropdown is missing.  Any ideas why the dropdown is not showing up in IE?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
   if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog();
        } else {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
            $('#employeeList').show(); //show the select box explicitly
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Kabilan, no luck though

Answer (score 0):

Is your code embedded in the .ready() method? Otherwise it will try and render your div that isn't ready yet. I.e.

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    // your code below
if ($.browser.msie) {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog();
        } else {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
        }

        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          },
          close: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        });

});
```